# What is Secure Shell or SSH? How does it work?

Tags: linux, security, authentication, ssh, terminal

I am in the process of setting up a digital ocean droplet. I have very little experience with networking and sysadmin tasks.

All of the documentation and tutorials about setting up this droplet highly suggests that I set up an SSH connection. Upon googling, I get very broad definitions and videos of what SSH is, but I cannot seem to conceptualize exactly how it works.

I've even followed the directions of the some of the tutorials without any issue, so apparently I've even accomplished doing this before with my other droplets. However, whenever I log into my droplet with PuTTY or WinSCP, I still need to provide a username and password (even if the password is saved, I need to type it in to save it).

Other pieces of information I've obtained:

- When stepping through this process, I noticed that linux will STILL ask me to create a passphrase. But, a lot of the reading I did seemed to suggest I would not need to for some reason.
- There is a public and private key. I can't seem to understand what each is for, or what's the difference.
- I don't do anything to my home computer. Is an SSH connection verifying that I am indeed logging into my server through my home computer? If that is in fact the case, how does this process know I am logging into my server with my home computer if I did not provide any information about my home computer at all? (Everything was done through PuTTY on my server remotely).
- According to a lot of what I read, after setting up SSH, you are then supposed to disable root user access. I'm just not seeing why.

I'm just not really understanding what it is that I'm doing when I create private and public keys. I still have to provide my username and a password when logging into my server with WinSCP and PuTTY. Am I doing something wrong? In reference to SSH; what am I doing? Why am I doing this? Am I doing it right despite the fact that I still have to provide a password when logging in?

If possible, take an "explaining this to a 5-year old" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuTTY is an SSH client, so you've already been logging into your server via SSH without knowing it. Public-private keys are just an alternative way to log in (besides password login). The way it works is that you generate a public/private key pair on your home computer. Then you give your public key to the server, and instead of logging in using your password (which requires you to type it in), you can log in automatically using your private key. Private key login is also considered much more secure than password-based login when it is done right.

There are already a lot of resources for explaining how public-private key encryption works, so here's one I found on Reddit:

> Another way of looking at it is the familiar box analogy. Imagine you want to send a briefcase of information to your friend across the US but need it to be locked so that thieves can't see it. Obviously you can't just put your own lock on there and send it because your friend doesn't have your key to that lock.
>
> The box analogy offers a solution. You put your own lock on the bag and send it to your friend. There, your friend also puts HIS own lock and sends it back. You then unlock your own lock with your key, meaning that the only lock left is your friend's lock. Send it back, and they can easily unlock it and take a look at the information. This is foolproof because a thief would need to know both lock's keys to open the briefcase.
>
> Computing uses a similar model but rather than locks and keys it uses one master lock that can be opened with combinations of three keys, one public key and two private ones that you and your friend each know. Also it takes into account the properties of prime numbers and modular arithmetic. When studying CS, I found that [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEBfamv-_do) helps a lot in understanding how the numberized process of locking and unlocking works.

Source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1kocba/eli5_rsa_algorithm_and_publicprivate_keys/cbr0l24

In addition, if you want to get public-private key login working with PuTTY, here's a tutorial on that (and it's even specific to digitalocean!):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-ssh-keys-with-putty-to-connect-to-a-vps